# Activity crashes if GPS not on, possible to use COARSE_LOCATION if GPS unavailable?

Tags: android

At the moment when I load this activity with the GPS turned off on the device it crashes the application.

How would I go about fixing this?

If possible it would also be amazing if the GPS was turned off to instead use the COARSE_LOCATION, not sure how easy that would be.

Any help would be hugely appreciated, code is below:

```
public class SunriseSunset extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public Button getLocation;
    public Button setLocationJapan;
    public TextView LongCoord;
    public TextView LatCoord;
    public double longitude;
    public double latitude;
    public LocationManager lm;
    public Spinner Locationspinner;
    public DateDialogFragment frag;
    public Button date;
    public Calendar now;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sunrisesunset);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
                setupActionBar();

        //Setting onClickListener for Calculate Sunrise/Sunset Button
        findViewById(R.id.CalculateSunriseSunset).setOnClickListener(this);

        //Sets up LocationManager to enable GPS data to be accessed.
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1,
                new MyLocationListener());

        //Declares Latitude and Longitude TextViews
        LatCoord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LatCoord);
        LongCoord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LongCoord);

        //Declares for Location Spinner/Dropdown
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

        //Date shit
        now = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = (Button)findViewById(R.id.date_button);
        date.setText(DateFormat.format("dd MMMM yyyy", Calendar.getInstance()));
        date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });

    }
    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    // More date shit
    @SuppressLint("CommitTransaction")
    public void showDialog() {  
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); //get the fragment   
        frag = DateDialogFragment.newInstance(this, new DateDialogFragmentListener(){      

        public void updateChangedDate(int year, int month, int day){                     
        now.set(year, month, day);
        date.setText(DateFormat.format("dd MMMM yyyy", now));             
        }  
          }, now);
        frag.show(ft, "DateDialogFragment");     }



    public interface DateDialogFragmentListener{
        //this interface is a listener between the Date Dialog fragment and the activity to update the buttons date
        public void updateChangedDate(int year, int month, int day);
    }

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        Locationspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Locationspinner);
        Locationspinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new LocationOnItemSelectedListener(
                        this));
    }

    //Sets locations for all the cities in the spinner
    public void setLocationAuckland() {LatCoord.setText("-36.85248273");LongCoord.setText("174.76391734");}
    public void setLocationBuenoAires() {LatCoord.setText("-34.606358325");LongCoord.setText("-58.38727463");}
    public void setLocationCalgary() 

    protected void showCurrentLocation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // This is called to find current location based on GPS data and sends
        // these values to the LongCoord and LatCoord TextViews
        Location location = lm
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        LongCoord.setText(Double.toString(longitude));
        LatCoord.setText(Double.toString(latitude));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalculateSunriseSunset);
        b.setClickable(false);
        new LongRunningGetIO().execute();
    }

    public class LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        //Reads in the web service
        protected String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity)
                throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
            InputStream in = entity.getContent();
            StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
            int n = 1;
            while (n > 0) {
                byte[] b = new byte[4096];
                n = in.read(b);
                if (n > 0)
                    out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
            }
            return out.toString();
        }

        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(SunriseSunset.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
           this.dialog.setMessage("Calculating...");
           this.dialog.show();
        }

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

            // Finds todays date and adds that into the URL in simple date format DD/MM
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
            String formattedDate = df.format(now.getTime());

            String finalURL = "http://www.earthtools.org/sun/"
                    + LatCoord.getText().toString().trim() + "/"
                    + LongCoord.getText().toString().trim() + "/"
                    + formattedDate + "/99/0";
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(finalURL);
            String text = null;

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,
                        localContext);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.getLocalizedMessage();
            }
            return text;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
            //Closes dialog box onPostExecute
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                  this.dialog.dismiss();
               }
            //Finds TextViews for Sunrise and Sunset values and posts results
            if (results != null) {
                try {

                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                            .newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    InputSource s = new InputSource(new StringReader(results));
                    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(s);
                    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                    TextView tvSunrise = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sunrise);
                    TextView tvSunset = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sunset);
                    tvSunrise.setText(doc.getElementsByTagName("sunrise").item(0).getTextContent());
                    tvSunset.setText(doc.getElementsByTagName("sunset").item(0).getTextContent());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalculateSunriseSunset);
            b.setClickable(true);
        }
    }



    class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //  preparation code here
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.LessonsTutorials) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Lessons.class));
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.PhotoTools) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Tools.class));
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.Glossary) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Glossary.class));
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.Help) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Help.class));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Thank you for looking

**EDIT:**

LogCat output as requested:

```
04-19 11:45:06.211: I/Adreno200-EGL(29691): Build Date: 12/10/12 Mon
04-19 11:45:06.211: I/Adreno200-EGL(29691): Local Branch: 
04-19 11:45:06.211: I/Adreno200-EGL(29691): Remote Branch: m/partner-android/jb-mr1-dev
04-19 11:45:06.211: I/Adreno200-EGL(29691): Local Patches: NONE
04-19 11:45:06.211: I/Adreno200-EGL(29691): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
04-19 11:45:06.241: D/OpenGLRenderer(29691): Enabling debug mode 0
04-19 11:45:10.215: D/AndroidRuntime(29691): Shutting down VM
04-19 11:45:10.215: W/dalvikvm(29691): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414a1930)
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691):    at richgrundy.learnphotography.SunriseSunset.showCurrentLocation(SunriseSunset.java:148)
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691):    at richgrundy.learnphotography.LocationOnItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(LocationOnItemSelectedListener.java:20)
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691):    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691):    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691):    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-19 11:45:10.225: E/AndroidRuntime(29691):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT:

Is it because I'm calling the GPS_PROVIDER here:

```
protected void showCurrentLocation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // This is called to find current location based on GPS data and sends
        // these values to the LongCoord and LatCoord TextViews
        Location location = lm
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        LongCoord.setText(Double.toString(longitude));
        LatCoord.setText(Double.toString(latitude));
    }
```

Comment: stacktrace from logcat please?

Comment: did you add the permission to the manifest                                                       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: @SankarV LogCat output added above

Comment: @John - Yes both permissions are in the manifest file :)

Comment: I think i have the answer for ur question,but am unable to post u the answer-am getting this msg when i try to post u the answer-"Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. "...so  let me try some way to provide u the answer

Comment: What line does `SunriseSunset.showCurrentLocation(SunriseSunset.java:148)` reference? Is it the `.getLastKnownLocation()` or is it setting one of the lat/lngs?

Comment: whts ur mail id...?i will fwd u the mail conatining the that piece of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any provider can be unavailable. So before requesting update always check

```
if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1,
            new MyLocationListener());
} else if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1,
            new MyLocationListener());
}
```

Also the LocationManager might be unavailable (devices or firmwares without Location features). so check for null also.
I hardly understand your goals, but from what I see I would do something like this

```
private boolean pending;

private LocationListener listener;
private LocationManager lm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    //your stuff
    listener = new MyLocationListener();
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onPostCreate(state);
    if (lm != null) {
        requestLocation();
    }
}


private void requestLocation() {

    if (!pending) {

        if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1,
                    listener);
            pending = true;
        } else if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1,
                    listener);
            pending = true;
        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (pending) {
        lm.removeUpdates();
    }
}
```

Edit about showCurrentLocation:

```
protected void showCurrentLocation() {
    // these values to the LongCoord and LatCoord TextViews
    Location location = lm
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        LongCoord.setText(Double.toString(longitude));
        LatCoord.setText(Double.toString(latitude));
    }
}
```

Comment: The best way is to put it in some method. It depends on what is your goal. To request once the Activity created it's okay to call it in onCreate(). To request every time your Activity gains focus call it in onResume(). You must also check whether location updates are already pending and don't forget to stop the updates when you don't need them, lm.removeUpdates(listener) in onDestroy() or onPause() (if was in onResume()) or on Button click event. It's up to you.

Comment: Implemented that example but it's still crashing and giving the same message:

Comment: Why woun't you learn to find out what's wrong for yourself? Is it still (SunriseSunset.java:148) which causes NullPointerException? Looks like your lm at that moment is null.